# Order Win32_NTLogEvent Query returns invalid query

Tags: c#, logging, event-handling, event-log, wmi-query

In my c# code I have the following

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); 
ObjectQuery queryError = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Application' AND (TimeGenerated > '" + date + "000000.000000-000' AND (Type='Error'))");
```

1) This works but when I try to ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC I get invalid query message. How can I do this query ordering by TimeGenerated?

```
ObjectQuery queryError = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Application' AND (TimeGenerated > '" + date + "000000.000000-000' AND (Type='Error')) ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC");
```

2) How can I write the same query limiting the results? I tried LIMIT 20 but I got the same invalid query message.

```
ObjectQuery queryError = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Application' AND (TimeGenerated > '" + date + "000000.000000-000' AND (Type='Error')) LIMIT 20");
```

Thanks

Comment: WQL, the WMI Query Language, is a **subset** of SQL.  Valid keywords are [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can see that ORDER BY is not supported.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I see it has a WITHIN Clause but I could not figure how to use it. Do you know how I should use it in my query?

Comment: You don't, it is only valid on the kind of queries that generate an event.  Win32_NTLogEvent has no events.  Events as in "Button.Click event", not "event log".